https://pkhorse.com/?page=1 not working and redirect to home in wordpress
I am using external content in wordpress homepage via include php for pagination in wordpress not working and redirect all (https://pkhorse.com/raja/admin.php?page=1[?page=1](https://pkhorse.com/raja/admin.php?page=1)pages to home but working on this link only https://pkhorse.com/raja/admin.php?page=1 please help
<div class="pagination">
    <?php if ($page > 1): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?= $page - 1 ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>" <?= $i == $page ? 'style="background-color: #0056b3;"' : '' ?>><?= $i ?></a>
    <?php endfor; ?>

    <?php if ($page < $totalPages): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?= $page + 1 ?>">Next</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

